# angularjs cant make initial value to chained dropdown

Tags: angularjs, chained

I managed to make a chained dropdown but i cant make them have initial value. im doing something like this:

```
<select ng-model="check" ng-options="check.name for check in checks"></select>
              <select ng-show="check.params" ng-model="parameter" ng-options="p.name for p in check.params"></select>
```

here is the an example of a single check:

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => existing_client
            [params] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => IsEnabled
                            [type] => boolean
                            [check_id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18
                            [name] => country
                            [type] => country_comparison
                            [check_id] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 19
                            [name] => affiliate_id
                            [type] => string_comparison
                            [check_id] => 1
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 14
                            [name] => created_at
                            [type] => date
                            [check_id] => 1
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 15
                            [name] => muid
                            [type] => string_comparison
                            [check_id] => 1
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20
                            [name] => region
                            [type] => string_comparison
                            [check_id] => 1
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 24
                            [name] => created_at_interval
                            [type] => interval
                            [check_id] => 1
                        )

                )

        )
```

Comment: If you could recreate your concept in a jsfiddle or a plunker, that could help us to recreate the issue and solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ng-model` for the `<select>` is `checked`.

You will need to filter your array for the item that you want to set to `$scope.checked` , or use whatever logic will determine this value